# Compile kernel to don't use initrd

Tags: linux, assembly, kernel, bootloader, panic

I'm using a custom bootloader written in asm to boot a debian 8. 
But the bootloader doesn't use the initrd. 
In order to boot the system I need to compile a kernel which has driver for my hard disk drive configured as "built-in". 
So, I've made this :

```
apt-get install linux-source
apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

And after I go in the linux-source folder and i do :

```
make menuconfig
```

in order to choose what i want to compile in my kernel. So i've choosen things like :

- ATA/ATAPI/MFM/RLL support
- ...

But I get a kernel panic with my custom bootloader and some times with GRUB. 
Can someone help me to choose what to compile in my Kernel ?

Thank's, 
Alexandre.

Comment: There is usually a message printed with the panic indication the cause of the panic.  Do you have that?

Comment: Yes I've that "unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0 0) "

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the kernel actually knows on which block device the root fs is located. Usually this information is passed to the kernel via [kernel commandline](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt), in a form like `root=/dev/sda1`, by the bootloader.